# RxSwift Two way binding with a BehaviorRelay<Any?>

Tags: swift, binding, rx-swift

I create a generic variable. This variable can be connected to a textField or an other interface element like a switch, for example. So the type of my variable will be Any so that I can store a bool, a string or something else.

```
var test: BehaviorRelay<Any?> = BehaviorRelay<Any?>(value: nil)
```

Then I try to connect my interface elements to this variable

```
(self.switch.rx.value <-> viewModel.test).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Or

```
(self.textfield.rx.text <-> viewModel.test).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

with this error `Cannot convert value of type 'BehaviorRelay<Any?>' to expected argument type 'BehaviorRelay<Bool>'` or `Cannot convert value of type 'BehaviorRelay<Any?>' to expected argument type 'BehaviorRelay<String?>'`

How can I do this with RxSwift?

You can find here my <-> func:

```
infix operator <->
func <-> <T>(property: ControlProperty<T>, variable: BehaviorRelay<T>) -> Disposable {        
    let bindToUIDisposable = variable.asObservable()
        .bind(to: property)
    let bindToVariable = property
        .subscribe(onNext: { n in
            variable.accept(n)
        }, onCompleted:  {
            bindToUIDisposable.dispose()
        })

    return Disposables.create(bindToUIDisposable, bindToVariable)
}
```

Comment: @duan Can I ask you more details about your answer?

Comment: I'm not a fan of such indiscriminate use of Subjects. Also, the `<->` can be simplified quite a bit. Use `bind(to:)` both ways instead of `subscribe` for one route.

Comment: @Charlotte Sorry it's my mistake, It wont't cause infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The two-way binding doesn't cause an infinite loop in this case because UI elements don't emit values when modified programmatically, they only do it when the user changes the value. If the user flips the switch, it gets pushed to the Subject [BehaviorRelay] which then pushes the value back to the switch, but it ends there.)

You would have to cast your Element to an `Any?` with map and map the Any? back into the proper type when going from the BehaviorRelay to the UI element. It's very clunky and unsafe to do that.

Better would be to make your BehaviorRelay's element the correct type. You're going to have to know the type in order to do anything useful with it anyway.

Comment: Hi @Daniel T. , I hv to learn RxSwift basics & Data transfer within multiple view controllers. Do u having any tutorials ? Can u pls guide me on this?

Comment: @McDonal_11 I asked him the same question. No reply. I will see all his answers on this site. If I live and work as an iOS developer.

Comment: Sorry I missed this. Handling data transfer within multiple view controllers can be done with my CLE library: https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools To learn the basics of Rx, I used http://introtorx.com The documentation that comes in the repo is also great: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/main/Documentation